# XML Serialization modifications

Tags: c#

I have created an XML using C# as below

[image: XML created]

For the above XML to be generated I have created the classes

1. ClientDocument.cs
2. TypeId.cs
3. RecordTarget.cs
4. Id.cs

Can I create the same XML without having to create a `RecordTarget.cs` class as it is just a container for `Id.cs`?

Comment: No you don't. Make `recordTarget` a property of `ClientDocument`

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work.

```
[Serializalble]
public class ClientDocument
{
  public Id[] recordTarget {get;set;}
}
```